# Can I deactivate the tooltip, that shows when I hover over an img-url in devtools code-window?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, tooltip

Can I deactivate the tooltip, that shows when I hover over an img-url in devtools code-window?
[tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsNLT.jpg)

The tooltip always covers the code. And if you have many imgs in your doc, it always shows unintentionally.

I looked for a checkbox in the devtools-settings but didn't find anything.
A google search didn't turn up anything either.